# Can't authenticate when using Gmail API

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform

Can't authenticate Gmail API no matter what I try. Using python.

I set up proper python code and I get

"Google hasn’t verified this app
You’ve been given access to an app that’s currently being tested. You should only continue if you know
that invited you."

then i click continue, and then i get:

"Something went wrong
Sorry, something went wrong there. Try again."

I've tried removing all 2 step authentication.

//

```
>! import statements

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
    ]

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    r'my_correct_path_to_secret_file'
    , scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'])
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

>! Save the credentials for the next run
with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
    token.write(creds.to_json())

>! Create the Gmail API client
gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO after the line "self.creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)" your default browser should be started with the correct link to consent (give the app permission) to do whatever it wants to do. Does your app have a test user connected to it?